# Best practices on reusing test inputs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, design-patterns, mocha.js

I've written a fixed-point math library, which comes in two flavors: the signed and the unsigned flavor.

The tests across the two flavors have lots of inputs in common. E.g. for the `avg` function:

```
// Signed tests inputs
context("when one operand is zero and the other is not zero", function () {
  const testSets = [
    [fp("-4"), fp("0")],
    [fp("0"), fp("-4")],
    [fp("0"), fp("4")],
    [fp("4"), fp("0")],
  ];
  // ...
});


// Unsigned tests inputs
context("when one operand is zero and the other is not zero", function () {
  const testSets = [
    [fp("0"), fp("4")],
    [fp("4"), fp("0")],
  ];
  // ...
});
```

The values in the `testSets` arrays are duplicated. Links to GitHub:

- [Signed tests](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math/blob/5f140e5ec3b8c88ead638ea4362a54c80abca74e/test/prbMathSd59x18/pure/avg.ts)
- [Unsigned tests](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math/blob/5f140e5ec3b8c88ead638ea4362a54c80abca74e/test/prbMathUd60x18/pure/avg.ts)

The question is, how to refactor my code base such that I don't repeat myself? Is there a "best practice" for this scenario? I read about [snapshot testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing), though that doesn't tackle test inputs. I said that maybe I should [fake](https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js) the data. But I'm not sure that makes sense in my case, because the inputs for my mathematical functions are bound by a domain.

Note: I am running my tests with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/).

Comment: Don't put details somewhere off-site: by all means add links to your "real" files on github, but only _in addition to_ [putting the details relevant to your post, in your post](/help/how-to-ask). If you move your repo to a different host, or you rename your branch, etc. this question will be completely useless to future visitors, which is why links are fine, but only in addition to having everything in your post here on SO.

Comment: I will add details in this post as well. FWIW I used CMD+Y to get a link to the GitHub commit, not the branch.

Comment: Then remember that any commit hash on github is liable to disappear at any point, because `git prune` exists.